# about next permutation algorithm

Tags: algorithm

Hi I am currently coding next permutation. my program passed 171 cases, but stopped at case

```
Input: [2,3,1] 
Output: [1,2,3] 
Expected: [3,1,2]
```

I can not figure out why the expected is [3,1,2].

The procedure of next permutation is that (copied from another thread):

1. iterate from end to begin, stop when we find an element that is smaller than the previous one encountered (suppose it's num[i], num[i] should be less than or equal to num[i+1], which is a).
2. now iterate from a to the end. find the smallest element b that is greater than a.
3. switch a and b.
4. reverse the segment from end to one after a.

For the case [2,3,1] , I think a = 2, b = 1, and after switching a and b, we have [1, 3, 2]. Then, reverse the segment, we have [1, 2, 3].

I understand I am wrong, but I can not figure out where is wrong. All I am doing is following the procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Smallest element b which is greater than a, here 3.